# How to install requirements.txt in django

Tags: python, django

I want to install all the dependencies in Django using requirements.txt.but I am getting an error

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Comment: The issue is quite clear. Without more information, we can't tell much more than the error already does. Post some more information, like project layout, what command you ran, what you've tried.

Comment: Also, higher quality questions have more chances of getting answers. And in the attempt of doing so, you might discover the source of the issue. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's a requirements.txt in your folder. Reading your error says that there's no file in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe accidentally ran the install command in a sub-folder or in a parent folder which would return this error. Check if you are running the command in the right folder (the one with requirements.txt).